# Backslash in string parameter unsuccessful in concatenating

Tags: bash

I have a URL that I curl in a bash function, and it is appended by a string parameter. The URL has backslashes in it, and they work fine. However, if there is a backslash in the parameter, it fails.

The important part is:

`curl "http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\bg_white&space;\huge&space;$1" > image.png`

Now, if the parameter is `"f(x)=x^{2}"` it'll work fine. But if I try `"f(x)=\sqrt{x}"` then I only get back the part before the backslash. I've tried single and double quotes on both parts, but nothing is working.

How do I pass a parameter with a backslash and then concatenate it with another string and still maintain the backslash?

Comment: What about a double backslash, e.g. `png.latex?\\bg_white...`

Comment: The bit of code that you've posted is the correct way to incorporate a parameter, whether or not that parameter contains a backslash. So your problem is either in how you're setting that parameter to begin with (which you haven't shown us), or in the site that you're calling (which would be a completely different question).

Comment: I've made an alias for the function, and I pass the parameter as I've written (i.e. `"f(x)=\sqrt{x}"`). Also, the URL for the site accepts single backslashes (as I stated it works without the parameter having backslashes, and the URL has some already).

Comment: Single backslashes are parsed as literal in single-quoted contexts, but not double-quoted contexts.

Comment: You could let curl take care of URL encoding with something like `curl -G "http://http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex" --data-urlencode '\bg_white&space;\huge&space;'"$1"`

Comment: Also, note that you can switch between quoting types within a single string. In `'\foo'"$bar"`, the first half is single-quoted (so the backslash is literal), and the second half is double quoted (so the parameter expansion takes place). Edit: I see Benjamin's comment above demonstrating that technique.

Comment: @BenjaminW. this works (except you have `http://http://` twice at the start). Submit as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your backslash into their url encoded format **%5C**

```
f(x)=%5Csqrt{x}
```

Comment: This returns the same as before (everything before where the backslash would be).

Comment: @MattBraddock: Then that proves it's not a Bash-related issue. (Bash doesn't know anything about `%5C`.) In the future, please spend some time identifying the issue before opening a question.

Comment: I tried with a php script, the php just print_r the query string ($_GET). 
curl "https://example.com/test.php?f(x)=%5Csqrt\{x\}"  the result is ok: 
Array
(
    [f(x)] => \sqrt{x}
)

Comment: @ruakh considering if I take the parameter and manually put it at the end of the URL and put it in the browser it will work, I fail to see how this is not a bash issue. Not to mention, one suggestion in the comments to my question answered the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @MattBraddock: It's not a Bash issue because it's not a Bash issue. The suggestion that worked for you did not change the Bash quoting for the parameter in question. (Are you maybe under the impression that `curl` is a part of Bash? Because it's not: it's its own program.)

Comment: @MattBraddock: (That said, I guess you did have a Bash issue as well -- it was just the opposite of what you thought it was. You thought the backslash wasn't working in the parameter, but in fact, that was the only place it *was* working. Some debugging with `echo` would have let you find that.)

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @benjamin-w in the question worked:

`curl -G "http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex" --data-urlencode '\bg_white&space;\huge&space;'"$1" > image.png`